# Why does 'yield' throw an error when used twice in saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I'm re-learning about sagas and I'm wondering why I'm getting this error on the `yield` towards the bottom. Do I need to wrap those two lines in another generator function and call that to mitigate the error and get this to build?

```
export default function* showPermissionWall() {
  yield takeLatest(SHOW_TIMED_LOGIN_WALL, function* () {

      setTimeout(() => {

        yield put(showPermissionsNeededWall('Please log in', null)); // Parsing error: yield is a reserved word in strict mode
        readTimeLoginBoxShown();

      }, 1000 * SHOW_LOGIN_WALL_AFTER_IN_SECONDS); // Show after 3 minutes of reading
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're callback function in the setTimeout is not a generator function.
Hence, you cannot use yield within it.

```
 setTimeout(function *() {

        yield put(showPermissionsNeededWall('Please log in', null));
        readTimeLoginBoxShown();

      }, 1000 * SHOW_LOGIN_WALL_AFTER_IN_SECONDS);
```

should be able to help you

Comment: I'm now getting an error in the function `This generator function does not have 'yield'.`

Comment: You don't need the function wrapping the setTimeout to be a generator function anymore. you can let it be a normal function

Comment: The problem with this is that the function wrapping `setTimeout` is my `yield takeLatest` generator function, so I need that :)

Comment: You could hack this:
`export default function* showPermissionWall() {
  yield takeLatest(SHOW_TIMED_LOGIN_WALL, function* () {

      yield call (setTimeout, function *()  {

        yield put(showPermissionsNeededWall('Please log in', null)); // Parsing error: yield is a reserved word in strict mode
        readTimeLoginBoxShown();

      }, 1000 * SHOW_LOGIN_WALL_AFTER_IN_SECONDS); // Show after 3 minutes of reading
  });`